# Linq, IQueryable get most frequent element object

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

My main problem lies in understanding `IGrouping<int, SubForm>`. I want the most frequent object (`MyClass`). This is the code I have now:

```
var subForm =
            classes.GroupBy(c => c.SubFormId)
            .OrderByDescending(sf => sf.Count())
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

This returns `IGrouping<int, SubForm>`. To get the actual object, I have to do another `FirstOrDefault()` but the compiler shows that there might be a null exception. 
This is the code to get the actual subform, can it be done better?

```
var subForm =
            classes.GroupBy(c => c.SubFormId)
            .OrderByDescending(sf => sf.Count())
            .FirstOrDefault().FirstOrDefault().SubForm;
```

Comment: Where does MyClass come in? It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: @JonSkeet, sorry, its the same as SubForm class.

Comment: So are you trying to get the *ID* of it, or the actual entity?

Comment: You are getting the first Count, can you post the 'other' FirstOrDefault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just check to make sure there is at least one item in your `classes` collection (so it is guaranteed there is at least one group) either at the end or the beginning:

```
if(classes.Any())
{
    var subForm = classes.GroupBy(c => c.SubFormId)
                         .OrderByDescending(sf => sf.Count())
                         .First().First().SubForm;

}
```

Or:

```
var topGroup = classes.GroupBy(c => c.SubFormId)
                      .OrderByDescending(sf => sf.Count())
                      .FirstOrDefault();

if(topGroup!=null)
  subForm = item.First().SubForm;
```

Comment: So I definatly need a null check

Comment: I would go for the first option - just make sure that there is at least one item in `classes` - then the rest will always work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
 var sfGroup = classes.GroupBy(c => c.SubFormId)
            .OrderByDescending(sf => sf.Count())                
            .FirstOrDefault();

  int count = sfGroup.Count();
  MyClass subForm = sfGroup.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just use `First`. It would throw an exception if nothing is found.

Answer (score 0):

```
var subForm = classes.GroupBy(c => c.SubFormId)
    .OrderByDescending(sf => sf.Count())
    .FirstOrDefault();

return subForm == null ? default(SubForm) : subForm.Select(s => s.SubForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a select:

```
var subForm = (
    from c in classes
    group c by c.SubFormId into g
    select g.Key)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```